# Gitlab push doesn't work from a specific computer

Tags: git, push, gitlab, pull

I am using gitlab `8.1.2` and gitlab-shell `2.6.5`.
For some reason, I can't upgrade my gitlab right now.
I have a student that can use is rsa key on github, but not on my gitlab.
I have tried to regenerate a key, create a new account, I keep having this error :

```
root@dev-04:/home/me/workspace/school/api# sudo -ume git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 335 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.
To git@git.site.com:school/api.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.site.com:school/api.git'
```

I have connected to the gitlab host, and check the presence of the sshkey.

I am using git client `2.1.4` while this student use `2.7.2`

I have checked keys permissions and everything is OK.
He is able to pull the project.
The project is part of a group on gitlab.
Student is part of the group with developers rights.
We have tried also with a project part of a user, error remain.

Does anyone has a quick fix so he can push ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by downgrading git client to `2.1.4`